# google "sub-search" possibility detection

Tags: search

If user types words "sub search amazon" into google, he can find result like: [image: sub search result of amazon]

How does Amazon does the search at the same time when user does seach with google directly (not with Amazon)? How can I perform such search as Amazon does on my own site?

Comment: Amazon doesn't appear when I search for that phrase.

Comment: oops! not "sub search google" but "sub search amazon" should be, sorry; updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that Google is searching Amazon at the same time you are searching Google. More likely that is an archived search results page that Google found in its own index. i.e. that search was done on Amazon some time before, was indexed by Google, and now your Google search is finding it.

RE how to perform this on your own site: Do you mean to have searches from Google search your site? Not really possible. But you can replicate this behavior by making sure that your results pages are in your sitemap.xml

You could build a list of "top searches" links on your site linking to search results pages (SERPs). This was your SERPs can be indexed by Google.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening in your example is that Amazon is submitting that link to google in their sitemap.  (Amazon has a much higher level connection to google than a plain sitemap but same idea).  So google see's it as a page.  The description you have underlined in red, is provided on the amazon page.  Make sense?  Let me know if you need more clarity.

So if you would want the same thing.  You would have to just include the search result pages in your sitemap.  However, make sure the pages are relevant to the search term.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try search queries such as:

- site:mydomain.com
- augeri (site:thoughtpuzzle.com | site:awesomeispossible.com) [search link](https://www.google.com/search?q=augeri%20%28site%3athoughtpuzzle.com%20%7C%20site%3aawesomeispossible.com%29)
- snowden site:*.gov -site:whitehouse.gov -site:cia.gov inurl:obama [search link](https://www.google.com/search?q=snowden%20site%3a%2a.gov%20-site%3awhitehouse.gov%20-site%3acia.gov%20inurl%3aobama)

Or creating a [Google Custom Search Engine](https://www.google.com/cse/) if you need to include or exclude more than than 10 and up to 5,000 specific web sites or web pages, such as this [mobile app search engine](https://www.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=partner-pub-3989641269425886:5048880850#gsc.tab=0).